# Ensure contents print on separate pages

Tags: html, css

I have a cover letter and resume together in seperate divs on one html web page.

When I try print preview half of my resume is on the cover letter page.

Is there any way to ensure that the two divs print on seperate pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following CSS...

```
#cover-letter {
   page-break-after: always;
}
```

Comment: oh wow thanks that worked really well. But for some reason it adds 3 blank pages after and then shows my resume =(

Comment: @Ellipsis I wouldn't be 100% sure without seeing the HTML too.